# How to use iPhone 4S connection for Internet in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: internet, iphone

Is it possible to use a iPhone 4S's cell connection for Internet in Ubuntu 13.04 via the charger cable without jailbreaking? My Internet sometimes gets frustratingly slow and it would be handy to have a second way to get Internet.

Thanks in advance, ~Roy.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. However it depends on your service provider whether it's free or not. You'll have to set a wifi hotspot using your device, this feature is in your settings on your device. Using the hotspot you can tether a connection that Ubuntu will automatically connect to when you plug your device in, or you can connect via wireless if your computer has wireless capabilities.

I know on Verizon and AT&T both you have to pay to activate the hotspot feature on your device, that's the only catch, but otherwise it's as simple as enabling the hotspot and plugging your device in via usb.